# program to determine number of duplicates in a sentence

Tags: java

Code:public class duplicate

{

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException

  {

  System.out.println("Enter words separated by spaces ('.' to quit):");

  Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  while (true)

  {

  String token = input.next();

  if (".".equals(token))

  break;

  if (!s.add(token))

  System.out.println("Duplicate detected: " + token);

  }

  System.out.println(s.size() + " distinct words:\n" + s);
 Set<String> duplicatesnum = new HashSet<String>();
```

String token = input.next();
if (!s.add(token))
{
    duplicatesnum.add(token);
    System.out.println("Duplicate detected: " + token);
}

System.out.println(duplicatesnum.size());

}
}
the output is:
Enter words separated by spaces ('.' to quit):
one two one two .
Duplicate detected: one
Duplicate detected: two
2 distinct words:
[two, one]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to know the number of different duplicate words. You can use another `HashSet<String>` for the duplicates.

```
//Outside the loop
Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<String>();

//Inside the loop
if (!s.add(token))
{
    duplicates.add(token);
    System.out.println("Duplicate detected: " + token);
}

//Outside the loop
System.out.println(duplicates.size());
```

Also if you care for the occurences of each word declare a `HashMap<String, Integer>` as in others posts is mentioned.

But if you want the number of all duplicate words(not different) just declare a counter:

```
//Outside the loop
int duplicates = 0;    

//Inside the loop
if (!s.add(token))
{
    duplicates++;
    System.out.println("Duplicate detected: " + token);
}

//Outside the loop
System.out.println(duplicates);
```

Comment: in my program it is not able to detect token?
wats the reason?
i have imported util package

Comment: What do you mean? "token" is your variable - "String token = input.next();"

Comment: yes i did it.
still its not working.
its running but not printing the number of duplicate words.

Comment: What do you mean? What is it printing? Do you manage to read the input?

Comment: it is printing the duplicate words only.not the number of duplicates detected.

Comment: Enter words separated by spaces ('.' to quit):
one two three two one .
Duplicate detected: two
Duplicate detected: one
3 distinct words:
[two, one, three]
this is the output

Comment: Have you put this line outside the loop: 
System.out.println(duplicates.size());

Comment: I have put "System.out.println(duplicates);" outside the loop.

Comment: If you want the number of duplicate words put - System.out.println(duplicates.size());

Comment: witing this ,it sats int cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: You are using the second solution I proposed. Use the FIRST one with Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<String>();

Comment: still its not printing the number

Comment: What do you get now? Please paste your code here - http://pastie.org/ so I can take a look at your current code.

Comment: Run only mine code. You have put mine code after the whole yours and the input has ended.

Comment: Isn't the issue that your solution will only show him which words were duplicated, and he wants to know which words AND how many times?

Comment: @Phil No, he wants the number of different duplicate words.

Comment: If he also wants the words, he can just print the duplicateNum set. What is so hard here?!

Comment: runnig only your code wont solve my problem.
why is it not printing the number?

Comment: Man, what do you mean? Here it is printing the number - System.out.println(duplicatesnum.size()); Put a breakpoint there and debug. Btw, are you sure you are running mine code?

Comment: And what is the damn program printing, when this line is executed - System.out.println(duplicatesnum.size()); ?!

Comment: What do you mean by not printing anything? The line is surely printing something - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, alabala or whatever you want, but it is printing something:)

Comment: No problem:) If you consider my answer correct, please accept it. It is a green tick on the left side of my post beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a HashSet, use a HashMap.  A HashSet only stores the values.  A HashMap maps a value to another value (see http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/47545 for an explanation)

In your case, the key of the HashMap is your string (just as the key of the HashSet is the string).  The value in the HashMap is the number of times you encountered this string.

When you find a new string, add it to the HashMap, and set the value of the entry to zero.
When you encounter the same string later, increment the value in the HashMap.

Comment: i dont want to make it complicated.using a hash map will be very lenghthy

Comment: @bhavna: It won't add that much to the length, and it's the most straightforward way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a `HashSet`, you will not know how many duplicates you have.  If you went with a `HashMap<String, Integer>`, you could increment whenever you found that your key was `!= null`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `if (!s.add(token))`, you can increment a counter and then display it's value at the end.

Comment: I think he wants the number of different duplicate words.

Comment: This give the number of duplicates globally, he didn't say if he wants it by duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit misleading. Some people understand that you want:

> **Input:** hello man, hello woman, say good by to your man.
>
> **Output:**
>
> Found duplicate: Hello
>
> Found duplicate: Man
>
> Duplicate count: 2

Others understood you wanted:

> **Input:** hello man, hello woman, say hello to your man.
>
> **Output:**
>
> Found duplicate: Hello - 3 appearances
>
> Found duplicate: Man - 2 appearances

Assuming you want the 1st option - go with **Petar Minchev**'s solution

Assuming you want the 2nd option - go with **Patrick**'s solution.  Don't forget that when you use an Integer in a Map, you can get/put `int` as well, and Java will Automatically Box/Unbox it for you, but if you rely on this - you can get NPEs when asking the map for a key that does not exist:

```
Map<String,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();    
myMap.get("key that does not exist"); // NPE here <---
```

The NPE is caused since the return value from 'get' is null, and that value is being cast into an `Integer` after which the `intValue()` method will be invoked - thus triggering an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google collections library](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/):

```
Multiset<String> words = HashMultiset.create();

while (true) {
    String token = input.next();

    if (".".equals(token))
        break;
    if (!words.add(token))
        System.out.println("Duplicate detected: " + token);
}
System.out.println(words.elementSet().size() + " distinct words:\n" + words.elementSet());

Collection<Entry<String>> duplicateWords = Collections2.filter(words.entrySet(), new Predicate<Entry<String>>() {
   public boolean apply(Entry<String> entry) {
      return entry.getCount() > 1;
   }
});
System.out.println("There are " + duplicateWords.size() + " duplicate words.");
System.out.println("The duplicate words are: " + Joiner.on(", ").join(duplicateWords));
```

Example of output:

```
Enter words separated by spaces ('.' to quit):
aaa bbb aaa ccc aaa bbb .
3 distinct words:
[aaa, ccc, bbb]
There are 2 duplicate words.
The duplicate words are: aaa x 3, bbb x 2
```

Comment: which package do i need to import?

Comment: You must download that library and add it to your path. The link is http://google-collections.googlecode.com/files/google-collect-1.0.zip